# Java, прокси, как проверить?

Tags: java, proxy

У меня есть список прокси примерно 1000шт. Как мне их быстро проверить?

Вероятно, есть какие-то сервисы, которые через API могут это сделать или какими-то командами это можно проверить самому, посоветуйте пож-та как решить задачу…

Нужно получить по каждому прокси следующие данные:

- конечный ip (стартовый и конечный ip могут быть разные)
- страна
- уровень анонимности (бывают: высоко анонимный, анонимный, прозрачный)
- какие протоколы поддерживает (HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS4, SOCKS5)
- время ответа

Comment: Что такое уровень анонимности? Что это за параметр (чисто технически)?

Comment: Анонимные прокси прячут ip с которого идёт обращение, прозрачные прокси нет